# Getting Datastore Key before inserting data

Tags: python, database, nosql, google-cloud-datastore

Cloud Datastore ([Entities, Properties, and Keys](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/concepts/entities)) allows entities to be identified with an automatically generated numeric ID (or enter a custom name).

I'd like to use the *automatically generated numeric ID* in some business logic **before** the entity is written to the Datastore.

```
from google.cloud import datastore

ds = datastore.Client('my-project-id')

# Use automatically generated numeric ID.
key = ds.key('MyEntity')

# https://googlecloudplatform.github.io/google-cloud-python/latest/datastore/keys.html
my_id = key.id()

# Some business logic requiring unique ID for MyEntity
data = my_business_logic(my_id)

entity = datastore.Entity(key=key)
entity.update(data)
ds.put(entity)
```

However, `key.id()` is `None` and so I get a Python TypeError:

```
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable
```

[Key is documented](https://googlecloudplatform.github.io/google-cloud-python/latest/datastore/keys.html), so perhaps I'm using the wrong getter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, entities won't have a complete key (with the numeric ID) until they're `put()` into the datastore.

For a case like yours where you want to know the auto-generated numeric ID before writing the entity to the datastore, you can use the datastore client's [`allocate_ids`](https://googlecloudplatform.github.io/google-cloud-python/latest/datastore/client.html#google.cloud.datastore.client.Client.allocate_ids) method, like so:

```
from google.cloud import datastore

ds = datastore.Client('my-project-id')

key = ds.allocate_ids(ds.key('MyEntity'), 1)[0]

my_id = key.id

data = my_business_logic(my_id)

entity = datastore.Entity(key=key)
entity.update(data)
ds.put(entity)
```

Note that `allocate_ids` takes 2 arguments, `incomplete_key` and `num_ids`, so even if you just want one key, you'll need to specify that and extract the first (and only) member of the resulting list.